# How to get 18.1 to get working on Monero GUI

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monerod, monero-forks, hard-fork

Im having a hard time getting the new 18.1 hardfork release to work on Monero gui. Please any help would be awesome. I logged in and it said download new version. i accepted but cannot seem to figure out how to get it running correctly.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? After the GUI downloads and verifies the new version, you still have to manually unpack it (i.e. unpack it yourself).

Comment: Im having issues with this upgrade too.
Im using Windows, I dont have much room so I use simple mode with a public node.
I upgraded to Flourine Fermi, including upgrade of my hardware wallet Ledger Nano S. Everything seemed ok, so I sent funds to my wallet.
I cannot for the life of me get the daemon to sync. I keep getting an error message that says Flourine Fermi unable to connect to daemon. Then it says its starting to try to connect again. Unable to connect over and over until it times out.
Ive tried shutting it down and restarting. Ive tried typing "monerod.exe", the same thing happens.
Th

Comment: @Guestperson1961 - Could you try to connect `node.community.rino.io` with port `18081` as dedicated remote node?

https://github.com/monero-ecosystem/monero-GUI-guide/blob/master/monero-GUI-guide.md#remote-node